# Best way to do block randomisation with covariates?

Tags: predictor, random-allocation, blocking

I have a set of $n$ objects for an experiment and I want to randomise them into a control group and treatment group with fixed sizes.  I would like to use [block randomisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(statistics)) to balance covariates, in order to get better results at the inferential stage.  (That is as clearly as I can pose the problem at this stage - I don't know exactly what specific optimisation I should do, and so I can't say exactly what "better" means yet.)

To undertake my block randomisation, I have an $n \times m$ covariate matrix $\boldsymbol{X}$ for these objects (with no missing data), where each row gives $m$ covariate values for an object.  I have also calculated the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) between each object to get an $n \times n$ distance matrix $\boldsymbol{D}$.  The size of my data-set is $n \approx 6000$ and $m \approx 30$.

I would like to be able to implement my chosen blocking method in R, without having to write a complicated package from scratch.  This means that I need a method that can be implemented on R with some known code, or with an existing package.  I have done some research on the literature for block randomisation, but I'm not sure what I should use.  From what I can tell from the literature, there are some possible optimisation problems that can be posed here, but computation can be an issue for large distance matrices.

**Questions:**

(1) Can anyone give a recommendation of a good method of block randomisation that I could use here that takes advantage of my covariates?

(2) How would this method be implemented in R code?

(3) Can anyone share any other relevant experience on this problem with me?

Answer (score 1):

1) I think if I am understanding you correctly you could use a k-means clustering feeding in your covariates to create your blocks. Set your K to the number of desired blocks, and then sample randomly from within each block.

2) kmeans(x = df, centers = desired number of blocks) #adjust iter.max and nstart as desired, its really a tradeoff between run time and accuracy
 From there just sample the desired number/proportion from each block.

3) I cannot, sorry. My answer is based solely off of my understanding of your question and clustering.

Comment: Does this method guarantee clusters (blocks) of equal size?  My understanding is that it doesn't.  Can that be corrected?

Comment: You're right, it would not guarantee equally sized blocks. Interesting question. I found this that might help https://elki-project.github.io/tutorial/same-size_k_means